# Using lookahead with generators

Tags: python, generator, regex-lookarounds

I have implemented a generator-based scanner in Python that tokenizes a string into tuples of the form *(token type, token value)*:

```
for token in scan("a(b)"):
    print token
```

would print

```
("literal", "a")
("l_paren", "(")
...
```

The next task implies parsing the token stream and for that, I need be able to look one item ahead from the current one without moving the pointer ahead as well. The fact that iterators and generators do not provide the complete sequence of items at once but each item as needed makes lookaheads a bit trickier compared to lists, since the next item is not known unless `__next__()` is called.

What could a straightforward implementation of a generator-based lookahead look like? Currently I'm using a workaround which implies making a list out of the generator:

```
token_list = [token for token in scan(string)]
```

The lookahead then is easily implemented by something like that:

```
try:
    next_token = token_list[index + 1]
except: IndexError:
    next_token = None
```

Of course this just works fine. But thinking that over, my second question arises: Is there really a point of making `scan()` a generator in the first place?

Comment: er... this one is not solely about strings, is it? thinking about things like `(_ for _ in (None, 'evil', 4, 0))`, that's a generator too..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can write a wrapper that buffers some number of items from the generator, and provides a lookahead() function to peek at those buffered items:

```
class Lookahead:
    def __init__(self, iter):
        self.iter = iter
        self.buffer = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.buffer:
            return self.buffer.pop(0)
        else:
            return self.iter.next()

    def lookahead(self, n):
        """Return an item n entries ahead in the iteration."""
        while n >= len(self.buffer):
            try:
                self.buffer.append(self.iter.next())
            except StopIteration:
                return None
        return self.buffer[n]
```

Comment: Really nice, both simple and flexible. I think this implementation mostly fits what I would have imagined, thank you.
By the way, I'm wondering how issues like that are commonly handled by scanners, parsers or the like in Python. I've gone threw some Python core library code like the SRE module or the tokenizer but I haven't seen something like a lookahead iterator being used.

Comment: You might use a deque for the buffer, although efficiency probably doesn't matter *too* much for small lookaheads.

Comment: would you provide an example of this?

Comment: ah. got bit by the old python2 vs python3 next issue. - still an example would be nice.

Answer (score 23):

Pretty good answers there, but my favorite approach would be to use `itertools.tee` -- given an iterator, it returns two (or more if requested) that can be advanced independently. It buffers in memory just as much as needed (i.e., not much, if the iterators don't get very "out of step" from each other).  E.g.:

```
import itertools
import collections

class IteratorWithLookahead(collections.Iterator):
  def __init__(self, it):
    self.it, self.nextit = itertools.tee(iter(it))
    self._advance()
  def _advance(self):
    self.lookahead = next(self.nextit, None)
  def __next__(self):
    self._advance()
    return next(self.it)
```

You can wrap any iterator with this class, and then use the `.lookahead` attribute of the wrapper to know what the next item to be returned in the future will be.  I like to leave all the real logic to itertools.tee and just provide this thin glue!-)

Comment: Great code. Note that implementing `__next__()` gave me "TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class IteratorWithLookahead with abstract methods next". Changing the method name to `next()` solved this. (CPython 2.7)

Comment: @bavaza It needs to be `__next__` on Python 3 and `next` on Python 2.

Comment: I just included both `next` and `__next__` for my code base.

Answer (score 6):

It's not pretty, but this may do what you want:

```
def paired_iter(it):
    token = it.next()
    for lookahead in it:
        yield (token, lookahead)
        token = lookahead
    yield (token, None)

def scan(s):
    for c in s:
        yield c

for this_token, next_token in paired_iter(scan("ABCDEF")):
    print "this:%s next:%s" % (this_token, next_token)
```

Prints:

```
this:A next:B
this:B next:C
this:C next:D
this:D next:E
this:E next:F
this:F next:None
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still thinking pre-Python3!  Changed to next_token instead.

Comment: scan() can be replaced by the builtin iter()

Comment: @NicDumZ: True. I thought about that, but I wanted to emulate the code in the OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example that allows a single item to be sent back to the generator

```
def gen():
    for i in range(100):
        v=yield i           # when you call next(), v will be set to None
        if v:
            yield None      # this yields None to send() call
            v=yield v       # so this yield is for the first next() after send()

g=gen()

x=g.next()
print 0,x

x=g.next()
print 1,x

x=g.next()
print 2,x # oops push it back

x=g.send(x)

x=g.next()
print 3,x # x should be 2 again

x=g.next()
print 4,x
```

Answer (score 3):

Construct a simple lookahead wrapper using [*itertools.tee*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```
from itertools import tee, islice

class LookAhead:
    'Wrap an iterator with lookahead indexing'
    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.t = tee(iterator, 1)[0]
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        return next(self.t)
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        for value in islice(self.t.__copy__(), i, None):
            return value
        raise IndexError(i)
```

Use the class to wrap an existing iterable or iterator.  You can then either iterate normally using *next* or you can lookahead with indexed lookups.

```
>>> it = LookAhead([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
>>> next(it)
10
>>> it[0]
20
>>> next(it)
20
>>> it[0]
30
>>> list(it)
[30, 40, 50]
```

To run this code under Python 3, simply change the *next* method to *__next__*.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you are tokenizing a string and not a general iterable, I suggest the simplest solution of just expanding your tokenizer to return a 3-tuple:
`(token_type, token_value, token_index)`, where `token_index` is the index of the token in the string.  Then you can look forward, backward, or anywhere else in the string.  Just don't go past the end.  Simplest and most flexible solution I think.

Also, you needn't use a list comprehension to create a list from a generator.  Just call the list() constructor on it:

```
 token_list = list(scan(string))
```

Comment: This is a very interesting idea since it avoids the issue in the first place. But I think there a two downsides: First, in case the part of accessing a token from the token stream is up to a different instance than the scanner, both token stream and original string would have to be provided.
However, I could live with that and it might be a good idea to let the scanner do the accessing work anyway.
But I think peeking a token by making use of the original string only provides the value but not other annotational stuff like the token's type which might be essential in some cases (so in mine).

Answer (score 0):

Paul's is a good answer. A class based approach with arbitrary lookahead might look something like:

```
class lookahead(object):
    def __init__(self, generator, lookahead_count=1):
        self.gen = iter(generator)
        self.look_count = lookahead_count

    def __iter__(self):
        self.lookahead = []
        self.stopped = False
        try:
            for i in range(self.look_count):
                self.lookahead.append(self.gen.next())
        except StopIteration:
            self.stopped = True
        return self

    def next(self):
        if not self.stopped:
            try:
                self.lookahead.append(self.gen.next())
            except StopIteration:
                self.stopped = True
        if self.lookahead != []:
            return self.lookahead.pop(0)
        else:
            raise StopIteration

x = lookahead("abcdef", 3)
for i in x:
    print i, x.lookahead
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would write it concisely, if I just needed 1 element's worth of lookahead:

```
SEQUENCE_END = object()

def lookahead(iterable):
    iter = iter(iterable)
    current = next(iter)
    for ahead in iter:
        yield current,ahead
        current = ahead
    yield current,SEQUENCE_END
```

Example:

```
>>> for x,ahead in lookahead(range(3)):
>>>     print(x,ahead)
0, 1
1, 2
2, <object SEQUENCE_END>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lazysequence`](https://pypi.org/project/lazysequence/), an immutable sequence that wraps an iterable and caches consumed items in an internal buffer. You can use it like any list or tuple, but the iterator is only advanced as much as required for a given operation.

Here's how your example would look like with lazy sequences:

```py
from lazysequence import lazysequence

token_list = lazysequence(token for token in scan(string))

try:
    next_token = token_list[index + 1]
except IndexError:
    next_token = None
```

And here's how you could implement lazy sequences yourself:

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence


class lazysequence(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iter = iter(iterable)
        self._cache = []

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self._cache
        for item in self._iter:
            self._cache.append(item)
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(1 for _ in self)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        for position, item in enumerate(self):
            if index == position:
                return item

        raise IndexError("lazysequence index out of range")
```

This is a naive implementation. Some things that are missing here:

- The lazy sequence will eventually store all items in memory. There's no way to obtain a normal iterator that no longer caches items.
- In a boolean context (`if s`), the entire sequence is evaluated, instead of just the first item.
- `len(s)` and `s[i]` require iterating through the sequence, even when items are already stored in the internal cache.
- Negative indices (`s[-1]`) and slices (`s[:2]`) are not supported.

The PyPI package addresses these issues, and a few more. A final caveat applies both to the implementation above and the package:

- Explicit is better than implicit. Clients may be better off being passed an iterator and dealing with its limitations. For example, clients may not expect `len(s)` to incur the cost of consuming the iterator to its end.

*Disclosure:* I'm the author of `lazysequence`.