# Implement lookahead iterator for strings in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm doing some parsing that requires one token of lookahead.  What I'd like is a fast function (or class?) that would take an iterator and turn it into a list of tuples in the form (token, lookahead), such that:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> list(lookahead(a))
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', None)]
```

basically, this would be handy for looking ahead in iterators like this:

```
for (token, lookahead_1) in lookahead(a):
  pass
```

Though, I'm not sure if there's a name for this technique or function in itertools that already will do this.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using lookahead with generators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517862/using-lookahead-with-generators)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are easier ways if you are just using lists - see Sven's answer. Here is one way to do it for general iterators

```
>>> from itertools import tee, izip_longest
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> it1, it2 = tee(iter(a))
>>> next(it2)  # discard this first value
'a'
>>> [(x,y) for x,y in izip_longest(it1, it2)]
    # or just list(izip_longest(it1, it2))
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', None)]
```

Here's how to use it in a for loop like in your question.

```
>>> it1,it2 = tee(iter(a))
>>> next(it2)
'a'
>>> for (token, lookahead_1) in izip_longest(it1,it2):
...     print token, lookahead_1
... 
a b
b c
c d
d None
```

Finally, here's the function you are looking for

```
>>> def lookahead(it):
...     it1, it2 = tee(iter(it))
...     next(it2)
...     return izip_longest(it1, it2)
... 
>>> for (token, lookahead_1) in lookahead(a):
...     print token, lookahead_1
... 
a b
b c
c d
d None
```

Comment: I would be wary of using this unless `SEQUENCE_END = object()` and `izip_longest(..., fillvalue=SEQUENCE_END)`, since the sequence itself may contain `None` (the default fillvalue).

Comment: @ninjagecko, The OP uses None in the question, which is happily the default fillvalue. I'm not sure I understand your point - the for loop is terminated when the iterator runs out, there is no problems having other `None`s in the sequence. The only time you need a distinct value there is if you need to special case the final iteration for some reason

Comment: @gnibbler: Consider the use-case where you want to use `lookahead` to determine if a sequence contains a double-repeated value, e.g. write a function `doesSequenceContainDoubleValue(sequence)`. If one used this implementation without a special `SEQUENCE_END` object, it would be an extremely tragic coding error if one merely said `any(x==nextX for x,nextX in lookahead(...))`, as one ought to be able to do.

Comment: @ninjagecko: sure, that is a case where it would be (hopefully obviously) necessary to have a distinct fillvalue, but again it is still only a problem in the case that the _final_ value of the sequence is also `None`.

Comment: @gnibbler: A minor simplification is to use `tee(it)` instead of `tee(iter(it))` -- these are equivalent for all iterables `it`.

Comment: it... doesn't seem to be `None`-safe.

Comment: @naxa. You can specify an alternate `fillvalue` for `izip_longest` if you don't want it to be `None`

Answer (score 8):

I like both [Sven's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448117/implement-lookahead-iterator-in-python/6448126#6448126) and [gnibbler's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448117/implement-lookahead-iterator-in-python/6448141#6448141) answers, but for some reason, it pleases me to roll my own generator.

```
def lookahead(iterable, null_item=None):
    iterator = iter(iterable) # in case a list is passed
    prev = iterator.next()
    for item in iterator:
        yield prev, item
        prev = item
    yield prev, null_item
```

Tested:

```
>>> for i in lookahead(x for x in []):
...     print i
... 
>>> for i in lookahead(x for x in [0]):
...     print i
... 
(0, None)
>>> for i in lookahead(x for x in [0, 1, 2]):
...     print i
... 
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, None)
```

**Edit**: Karl and ninjagecko raise an excellent point -- the sequence passed in may contain `None`, and so using `None` as the final lookahead value may lead to ambiguity. But there's no *obvious* alternative; a module-level constant is possibly the best approach in many cases, but may be overkill for a one-off function like this -- not to mention the fact that `bool(object()) == True`, which could lead to unexpected behavior. Instead, I've added a `null_item` parameter with a default of `None` -- that way users can pass in whatever makes sense for their needs, be it a simple `object()` sentinel, a constant of their own creation, or even a class instance with special behavior. Since most of the time `None` is the obvious and even possibly the expected behavior, I've left `None` as the default.

Comment: I would just `yield prev,` the last time. That way you can tell you're at the end because there's only one item. Your iterable might contain `None` in the sequence, after all. Or at least, use a special object that indicates the end of the sequence.

Comment: @Karl, interesting point -- but wouldn't `yield prev,` cause unpacking to break? A special object could work though...

Comment: It would indeed, so that's definitely a point for adding something.

Comment: +1 I went ahead and wrote an answer, and realized my code was 100% identical. Well almost 100%... I would do `SEQUENCE_END = object()` and return that at the end instead of `None`; this is very important in case the sequence may contain `None`. EDIT: @Karl: darn, everyone is spot-on correct tonight

Comment: @Karl, @ninjagecko, good points -- I decided to add a `null_item` parameter rather than hard-code it though.

Comment: `null_item` seems like the wrong name, expressing likely form rather than purpose - maybe `end_marker`?

Answer (score 6):

The usual way to do this for a list `a` is

```
from itertools import izip_longest
for token, lookahead in izip_longest(a, a[1:]):
    pass
```

For the last token, you will get `None` as look-ahead token.

If you want to avoid the copy of the list introduced by `a[1:]`, you can use `islice(a, 1, None)` instead.  For a slight modification working for arbitrary iterables, see the [answer by gnibbler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448117/implement-lookahead-iterator-in-python/6448141#6448141).  For a simple, easy to grasp generator function also working for arbitrary iterables, see [the answer by senderle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448117/implement-lookahead-iterator-in-python/6448281#6448281).

Comment: The OP asks about doing this on an iterator, but this assumes a list.

Comment: I also would be wary of using this unless `SEQUENCE_END = object()` and `izip_longest(..., fillvalue=SEQUENCE_END)`, since the sequence itself may contain `None` (the default fillvalue).

Comment: @Nick one could modify this to work on not-just-lists by using `itertools.tee`

Comment: @ninjagecko Indeed one could - I'm pointing out that your answer as it stands doesn't address the question as the OP asked it.

Answer (score 2):

You might find the answer to your question here: [Using lookahead with generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517862/using-lookahead-with-generators).

Answer (score 1):

**I consider all these answers incorrect, because they will cause unforeseen bugs if your list contains `None`.** Here is my take:

```
SEQUENCE_END = object()

def lookahead(iterable):
    iter = iter(iterable)
    current = next(iter)
    for ahead in iter:
        yield current,ahead
        current = ahead
    yield current,SEQUENCE_END
```

Example:

```
>>> for x,ahead in lookahead(range(3)):
>>>     print(x,ahead)
0, 1
1, 2
2, <object SEQUENCE_END>
```

Example of how this answer is better:

```
def containsDoubleElements(seq):
    """
        Returns whether seq contains double elements, e.g. [1,2,2,3]
    """
    return any(val==nextVal for val,nextVal in lookahead(seq))

>>> containsDoubleElements([None])
False  # correct!

def containsDoubleElements_BAD(seq):
    """
        Returns whether seq contains double elements, e.g. [1,2,2,3]
    """
    return any(val==nextVal for val,nextVal in lookahead_OTHERANSWERS(seq))

>>> containsDoubleElements([None])
True  # incorrect!
```

Comment: This answer is clearly **wrong** because the example given in the question **is padded with `None`**. I can see your point but you are answering the wrong question