# Does python have any builtin or standard-library lookahead mechanism for iterators?

Tags: python, iterator, regex-lookarounds

In principle it is easy enough to write a wrapper for iterators, that allows arbitrary look-ahead, and some questions have been dedicated to that (e.g. [Using lookahead with generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517862/using-lookahead-with-generators)).

However, given that pretty much every non-trivial file-parsing would profit from such a facility, it seems like too obvious an oversight for the standard library; Is there really no ***builtin or standard-library*** mechanism, that would allow peeking?

Specifically, I usually need peeking that works across function calls: A subfunction should be able to inspect an arbitrary number of upcoming elements, without removing them from the iterator – essentially a queue data type, where the elements are taken lazily from an iterator.

In some cases, `collections.deque` or `itertools.tee` can be used to construct workarounds. For the sake of code-readability, they are however unfavorable.

Comment: How about no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

---

I often find myself using the [`pairwise` Recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to lookahead...

```py
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

for item, peek in pairwise(iterable):
    ...
```

Or simply turn your iterable into a Sequence (if it's not already) and use indexed lookups.

```py
for index, item in enumerate(sequence):
    try:
        peek = sequence[index+1]
    except IndexError:
        peek = None
```