# Overwriting an iterator using itertools.tee

Tags: python, python-itertools

I would like to use `itertools.tee` inside of a function, with the original iterator as an argument, but I am concerned that I may be reusing the old iterator when I exit the function, which one is not supposed to do when using `tee`.

If I call tee in the same block as the iterator, then it seems safe:

```
my_iter = create_some_iterator()

my_iter, my_lookahead = itertools.tee(my_iter)
```

because the original iterator pointed to by `my_iter` has (I assume) no more reference counts and `my_iter` now points to its duplicate, so there's no way to use the original iterator.

But is this still true if I pass it through a function?

```
def foo(some_iter):
    some_iter, some_lookahead = itertools.tee(some_iter)
    # Do some lookahead tasks

my_iter = create_some_iterator()
foo(my_iter)
next(my_iter)   # Which iter is this?
```

Does `my_iter` point to the copy of `my_iter` after leaving the function?  Or does it still point to the original iterator, which I am not supposed to use?

I am concerned because most of the time this is not a problem, but there are occasions where I have been caught by this, particularly in less common implementations like PyPy.

---

This is what `id` tells me in the example above, which suggests that I cannot use iterators in this way, but I may also be misinterpreting what `id` means here:

```
import itertools

def foo(some_iter):
    print('  some_iter id:', id(some_iter))
    some_iter, some_lookahead = itertools.tee(some_iter)

    print('  new some_iter id:', id(some_iter))
    print('  some_lookahead id:', id(some_lookahead))
    # Do some lookahead tasks

my_iter = iter(range(10))
print('my_iter id:', id(my_iter))
foo(my_iter)

print('my_iter id after foo:', id(my_iter))
```

Output:

```
my_iter id: 139686651427120
  some_iter id: 139686651427120
  new some_iter id: 139686650411776
  some_lookahead id: 139686650411712
my_iter id after foo: 139686651427120
```

`my_iter` still has its original `id`, not the one assigned to `some_iter` by `tee`.

---

*UPDATE:* Sorry, this was not the question I meant to ask.  I more or less answer it myself in the second part.

I was more asking why it still seems to work as expected, with iterations in the copy are reflected in the original, even though they have different IDs.

Also was half-trying to ask how to handle this problem but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517862/using-lookahead-with-generators) provides a solution.

I tried to scale back the question, but scaled it back too much.

I tried to close this question, but it won't let me anymore, so not sure how to handle this.  Apologies to those who already answered.

Answer (score 0):

> Does my_iter point to the copy of my_iter after leaving the function? Or does it still point to the original iterator, which I am not supposed to use?

It still points to the original. Python is a "pass by value" language (though all its values are references so it's a bit confusing sometimes). It is *not* a pass-by-reference language, assigning to a parameter is purely local to a function and invisible from the caller.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, passing something to a function *never* makes a copy.

```py
def identity(x):
    return x

iter1 = iter(range(10))
iter2 = identity(iter1)
assert iter1 is iter2  # assert "object equality"
```

Python functions always work this way.

The behavior of `itertools.tee` is irrelevant. The fact that we are dealing with iterators specifically is irrelevant.

The fact that `itertools.tee` returns a *copy*, is behavior specific to `itertools.tee`.

If you have some free time, this talk can be very enlightening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns